# User Form referencing another sheet Run-time error '1004':

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am trying to get a user form list box to populate the values in a range from another sheet and getting this error. I have spent so much time working on it to no avail. I understand that excel cannot see the referenced sheets "Products" and "Locations", but I don't understand why.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim LocationsList, ProductsList, Location, Product As Range

Set LocationsList = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Locations").Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown))
Set ProductsList = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Products").Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown))

For Each Location In LocationsList
    ListBoxLocations.AddItem Location.Value
Next

For Each Product In ProductsList
    ListBoxProducts.AddItem Product.Value
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You can't assume that everything in the chain of `Sheets().Range( , Range())` succeeds as your code does. Use intermediate variables to see which part is failing. You certainly can't just pretend that everything worked and then start using `LocationList` and its contents without finding out whether it's valid or not first. Declare a separate variable that will hold the result of accessing `ActiveWookbook.Sheets()` and make sure that the specified sheet was found. Use another variable to hold the result of your `Range` calls. Figure out which one failed, and then you can figure out why.

Comment: `Dim LocationsList, ProductsList, Location, Product As Range` declares only `Product As Range`. All others are Variants (no type declared). However, VBA seems to deal with that. Therefore focus on your range setting. A range is set by defining its first and last cells, like `With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set LocationsList = .Range(.Range("B2"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
    End With`. In this example, the first cell is `.Range("B2")` with a leading period to connect it to the `With` that specifies the sheet. `.Cells(2, 2)` or .`Cells(2, "B")` would be clearer

Comment: The second cell is ` .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)` which, translated says, "looking at the last row in the sheet *(.Rows.Count)* go `up` until you encounter the `End` of the column, and give me that cell (a range consisting of one cell). Your syntax is a very bad imitation of that. The first one seems to work, miraculously. The second one doesn't. The difference seems to be what O wrote into the cells. The reason is the wrong syntax.

Comment: @Variatus Thank you for this. My range selection syntax comes from the way excel records the macro when you select B2 and do ctrl+shift+down arrow. It's also the way I was taught in school :/ Utilizing this code I was able to get the first for each loop to execute but not the second. Got hit with the object required runtime error.

Comment: Thank you for you help on this. I am still curious as to why the other way didn't work. It is the first time I have run into this issue.

Comment: I haven't been able to pinpoint the error either, noting that `LocationsList` and `ProductList` has the exact same syntax. However, for what it's worth, `Range("B2").End(xlDown)` finds the first empty cell in a range extended from B2 down.

Comment: Posted an answer and explanation to your issue; if helpful feel free to accept by ticking the green checkmark  :-) @Smokeybear001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use fully qualified range references**

First of all it would be correct to declare all variables in the 1st code line `As Range`, otherwise they are seen `As Variant`:

```
   Dim LocationsList As Range, ProductsList As Range, Location As Range, Product As Range
```

2nd) The main issue raising Error 1004 is that a not qualified range reference  `Range("B2").End(xlDown)` always refers to the range in the active worksheet.
As in one of both settings the internal range refers to another sheet, you can't avoid error.

*Further hint: Write a stop in between to test and change your sheet selection manually before running the userform.* Therefore it's not correct to say that `The first one seems to work, miraculously.`, it's only because the active worksheet may be the `Locations` sheet.

**Working code**

The long version of setting the first range to memory would be e.g.

```
 Set LocationsList = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Locations").Range("B2", ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Locations").Range("B2").End(xlDown))
```

This could be abbreviated by using the sheet's CodeName such as e.g. Sheet1 (of course you can change it in the VB Editor's Tool Window ~> `(Name)` property to the *normal* Excel sheet name)

```
Set LocationsList = Sheet1.Range("B2", Sheet1.Range("B2").End(xlDown))
```

or use a `With ...` statement as shown below

**Example code close to your OP**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim LocationsList As Range, ProductsList As Range, Location As Range, Product As Range
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Locations")
    Set LocationsList = .Range("B2", .Range("B2").End(xlDown))
End With
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Products")
    Set ProductsList = .Range("B2", .Range("B2").End(xlDown))
End With

For Each Location In LocationsList
    ListBoxLocations.AddItem Location.Value
Next

For Each Product In ProductsList
    ListBoxProducts.AddItem Product.Value
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a great explanation. Thank you so much.